# What is the most efficient way to make and odds system?

Tags: php, math, random, probability

I'm trying to design an odds system that goes from 1-100, however it also uses 0-1 for rarer odds.

I was told I should use a floating point format, but I don't know that.

Basically I have..

```
if (mt_rand(1,1000)/100 == $odds) {} else if (mt_rand(1,100) == $odds) {}
```

however that only yields the same probability.

I looked up floating point format in the PHP manual, but the answers there couldn't help me.

Comment: If you're going to vote for a close, at least give a comment/reason why... this is a programming logic question, I fail to see why it should be closed.

Comment: Did I do something wrong in asking the question? =/

Comment: A probability is a ratio, a ratio can be represented as a decimal, a floating point is a decimal. just do the calculation :-) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds

Comment: Right, I understand the mathematical logic to an extent, however I don't know the proper syntax to get a floating point (basically a rand(0,1) value)

Comment: @PRPG - In my opinion your question was fine

Comment: I'm not sure that your logic is correct.  I would think that you would use a `>` or `<` operator instead of a `==`, but it is possible I don't quite understand what you're doing.

Comment: Don't understand the question either. I guess this is one of the cases where you shouldn't show the code that you have, but the data you expect and the outcome in an examplary list.

Comment: The logic is: $odds is either a decimal .01-.99 or a whole number 1-100. I can't figure out the syntax to make the .01-.99 value work hand in hand with the whole number option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Odds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds) to understand how to convert your odds to a probability. If you have odds of `4:1` then there is a `1/5 == 0.2` probability of the event. If your odds are `.2:1` then there is a `5/6` (about .833) probability of the event happening. In general, if the odds are `m:n` against then the probability is `n/(m+n)`.

Now, if you want to simulate whether an event occurs or not, you need to get a random floating point number between `0` and `1` then check if this is less than the probability of the event. You can use something like `mt_rand(0,1000)/1000` to get a random number between `0` and `1`.

Examples:

```
$odds1 = 4; // 4:1
$prob1 = 1/($odds1+1); // 1/5

if( mt_rand(0,1000)/1000 <= $prob1 ) {
// event happened
}

$odds2 = .2; // .2:1
$prob2 = 1/($odds2+1);  // 5/6

if( mt_rand(0,1000)/1000 <= $prob2 ) {
// event happened
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating point values are inexact. (See [Why does `intval(19.9 * 100)` equal `1989`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497420/why-does-intval19-9-100-equal-1989) and [search: php floating point inexact](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20floating%20point%20inexact).)

You cannot use `==` for floating point values. A simple `5/10 == 0.5` might already be wrong due to inherent precision loss.

You can either round numbers before comparison, your what I'd advise in your case, pre-convert floats into integers:

```
     #       52    ==       100*0.52
if (mt_rand(1,100) == round(100*$odds)) {
```

Instead of comparing `0.99` with another float, you convert your odds into an integer `99` and compare it with an integer random in the range `1` to `100`. If odds already was an integer, not a float, then the `*100` multiplication will already cut it out of that first (faux float) comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($odds < 1){
   // floating point math here
   if((float)mt_rand(0,100) / 100.0 < $odds){
      echo "you're a float winner, harry";
   }
}else{
   if(mt_rand(0,100) < $odds){
      echo "you're an int winner, harry!";
   }
}
```